# Where does refused medicaid expansion money go?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, economy

Presumably, the money for medicaid expansion is there somewhere; i.e. the taxes for it have already been paid.  If a state declines to take those funds, where do they go?

Edit:
Avi, if you'd like to post your response as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: This isn't really how budgeting works; for the most part, taxes aren't earmarked for a specific purpose. It just goes into the federal budget.

Comment: This ignores the obvious point that if "the money" already existed, the national debt wouldn't continue to increase every year.